# Улучшение перевода термина "off-topic"

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, локализация

В текущем переводе термин "off-topic" переводится просто как "не по теме". Из-за этого в некоторых ситуациях это выглядит несколько не по-русски. Примеры:

> [image: закрыт]

> [image: требует правки]

Не хочу в этом довольно часто попадающемся на глазах моменте пользоваться своим локализаторским ромбом, поэтому предлагаю обсудить возможные варианты и принять какое-то устраивающее всех решение. Может быть вовсе оставить без изменений (хотя мне не хотелось бы).

Comment: Пф, при [tag:модераторском-произволе] модер делится властью :)

Comment: Альтернативный вариант: заменить «по причине того, что» на «ибо»

Comment: @defaultlocale и добавить «нефиг» :)

Answer (score 3):

Предлагаю в этих ситуациях писать:

> не соответствует тематике

Можно добавить в конец ещё слова "сайта", но это не обязательно.

Comment: Учитывая то, что off-topic в этом контексте прилагательное, то скорее "не соответству**ющий** тематике". UPD: правда, тут "так как", а не "как"...

Comment: @D-side вполне себе глагол. Но это не главное, с формами разберёмся. Главное - избавиться от "не по теме", по-крайней мере в части строк, выдаваемых движком. Запрещать так писать пользователям задачи не стоит :)

Comment: Так. А в транзифексе эти два контекста пользуются разными строчками? Или у них есть общая часть?

Comment: @D-side причина закрытие подставляется как переменная. Т.е. в обоих упомянутых случаях будет одинаковой.